# Finding min/max values in a KafkaStream (KStream) object

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I have a Kafka Stream application and Avro schemas for each of the topics and also for the key. Key topic schema is same for all.

Now, there is a KafkaStream (KStream) object with the known key object as the key and a value object (derived from the AvroSchema) which extends `org.apache.avro.specific.SpecificRecordBase` but it could be any of my avro schemas for the topic content.

`KStream<CustomKey, ? extends SpecificRecordBase> myStream = ...`

What I want to achieve is to run min and max functions on this stream. The problem is that I don't know what is the `?` object, and as there are 30+ (and will increase in the future) topics, I don't wanna do a switch-case. So I have the followings:

```
public KStream<CustomKey, ? extends SpecificRecordBase> max(
    final KStream<CustomKey, ? extends SpecificRecordBase> myStream,
    final String attributeName) {

    SpecificRecordBase maxValue = ...;
    myStream.foreach((key, value) -> {
      value.get(attributeName) // I want to find the max value for this attribute, 
                               // but at this point we don't know it's type and
                               // and we can't assign maxValue = value, because this is a lambda 
                               // function.
    });

    // find and return the max value
  }
```

My question is, how can I calculate the max value for the `myStream` on the `attributeName` attribute?

Answer (score 0):

> it could be any of my avro schemas for the topic content

Then you need to `extends ClassWithMinMaxFields`. Otherwise, you will be unable to extract it from generic `SpecificRecordBase` object.

Also, your method returns a stream. You cannot `return` the min/max. If that is your objective, you need a plain consumer to scan the whole topic, beginning to (eventual) end.

To do this (correctly) with Streams API, you would either

1. need to build a KTable for every value, grouped by key, then do a table scan for the min/max, as you need them.
2. Create a new topic using [`aggregate` DSL function](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/streams/developer-guide/dsl-api.html#aggregating), initialized with `{"min": +Inf, "max": -Inf}`, then on new records you check old vs new records, if you have a new min and/or max, set them and return the new record. Then, you still need an external consumer to fetch the most recent min/max events.
3. If you had a consistent Avro type, you could use [ksqlDB functions](https://docs.ksqldb.io/en/latest/developer-guide/ksqldb-reference/aggregate-functions/#max)

Comment: Could you give a short example implementation please? I couldn't implement it yet.

Comment: Look at the parameters for the aggregate function. There's an initializer function and another one that returns a new object